# Как при клике на объект из map получить в следующей панели, данные именно этого объекта?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vkontakte-api

У меня есть первая панель, где есть список людей, кликая на одного из них, я должен открыть страницу именно с его именем, вот первая панель, в которой есть список:

```
<Group>
   {getProfiles?.items?.map(res =>
                  <SimpleCell
                    style={{ padding: '5px 15px 5px 15px' }}
                    after={ <Avatar size={48} src={res.friend_photo} /> }
                    onClick={() => setActivePanel('profileUser') }
                  >
                      <Text>{res.friend_first + ' ' + res.friend_second}</Text>
                        <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '10px', alignItems: 'center', color: '#818C99' }}>
                            <div className='grid_avatar' style={{ marginTop: '2px' }}>
                                {res.groups.slice(0, 3).map(res => {
                                    return <Avatar src={res.photo} size={20} />
                                  }
                                )}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <Text style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>{res.groups.slice(0, 1).map(res => res.name)} и еще {res.groups.map(res => res.length)}</Text>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </SimpleCell>
                )}       
</Group>
```

Вот вторая панель, при где надо как то получить имя того, на кого перешел с прошлой панели.

```
import React from "react";

const ProfileUser = ({ getProfiles }) => {

  console.log(getProfiles)

  return (
    <div>
      {getProfiles.items.map(res => res.friend_first)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileUser;
```

Comment: Как Group и ProfileUser связаны между собой? Где рендерится ProfileUser?

Answer (score 0):

В пропсе `onClick` нужно передавать функцию, в которой будет логика открытия страницы выбранного человека. Чтобы определить кого выбрали, нужно в эту же функцию передавать какой-то уникальный идентификатор, по которому можно определить этого человека, из переменной `res`

Например: `onClick={() => handleOpenPage(res.id)}`